# Why is the voltage at the output of the RC differentiator equal to the input voltage source at the rising edge of the square wave

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, analog

[image: RC Differentiator]

[image]

- At the start V<sub>IN</sub> goes from 0 to V<sub>IN</sub>.
- Voltage across resistor is given by V<sub>out</sub> = R × i<sub>C</sub>.
- I<sub>C</sub> = C × dv/dt so V<sub>out</sub> = RC(dv/dt).
- For ideal square wave the dv/dt is infinite.

So shouldn't V<sub>out</sub> be infinite or a very large number, how do we get V<sub>out</sub>=V<sub>in</sub> at the rising edge of the square wave?

Comment: At t=0 dV is also 0 across cap on the step pulse so output=input. Actually it is attenuated by the ratio of source to load R + source resistance. dV/dt will have an initial slope of  dV/dt=I/C= V/RC then reduce as V lowers to 0 exponentially.

Comment: \$i_C = C \frac{v_C}{dt} \neq C \frac{v_{in}}{dt}\$. Remember that \$v_C = v_{in} - v_R\$ and \$i_C = i_R = C \frac{v_C}{dt} = v_R/R\$ and \$v_o = v_R\$. Eliminate v_c from the equation.

Comment: Ya dVin/dt is infinite, but dVc/dt is not infinite. Did you forget the resistor which controls the rise and fall times?

Answer (score 4):

Your basic understanding of the RC differentiator is correct...
Its basic operation comes from the current in the capacitor as a result of a driving voltage: \$ I_c = C \times {{d v_{in}}\over{d t}}\$.

So far, no resistor appears...but we need one to convert the capacitor's current into an output voltage. We must choose a small-value resistor, so that **all of \$V_{in}\$** appears across the capacitor. Any voltage that appears across this *current-sensing* resistor is subtracted from the voltage across the capacitor and introduces error.

Applying a square wave introduces a bad error on its leading edge, where for a short moment, resistor voltage is almost equal to Vin, and capacitor voltage is a fraction of Vin. What *should be* an almost infinite output voltage is corrupted by this error, and ends up being no larger than Vin.
For wave shapes other than square, like sine or triangular, the output voltage (voltage across the resistor) remains small compared to Vin, and this type of differentiator works well.

Consider that this differentiator is an approximate one where conditions apply:

- \$ {1\over{RC}} >> f_{in}\$
- \$ V_{in} >> V_{out}\$

For the square wave, think of its frequency components. While the fundamental frequency (1/period) of Vin must comply with the first condition, harmonics of the fundamental frequency can not, for they extend to much higher frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

Ic = Cdv/dt

Where dv/dt is the rate of voltage change across the capacitor.

For an ideal square wave it is the rate of change of voltage across the resistor that is infinite not the rate of change of voltage across the capacitor.

For an ideal square wave the trailing edge of the capacitor simply follows the leading edge on the square wave edges.

Comment: I made a mistake mathematically and I think I understand why Vout=Vin as Vout = Vin - Vin*(1-e^-t/RC) so if we substitute t=0 we get output is equal to input at rising edge of square wave. What I am struggling to understand is psychically why does that voltage pass the capacitor and present itself to the output without the capacitor being charged. Or is the capacitor instantaneously charged as soon as Vin goes high? If so how can the capacitor instantaneously be charged when there is a resistor in the way limiting the current?

Comment: Apply KVL to find how the input voltage divides between the two components. That should give a hint about why vin initially *steps over* the capacitor and appears across the resistor.

Comment: @maldingRookie Exactly - the capacitor can't be instantly charged "when there is a resistor in the way limiting the current" the charging current at the rising edge point is limited to Vin/R (or Vout/R). If the resistor equaled zero Ohms (right hand side of cap shorted to ground) and an ideal square wave was applied to left hand side of cap then the charging/discharging current would be infinite but of course infinite speed of those rising/falling edges is only a theoretical situation so in reality you could never get infinite current.